# Spoof txt and number

Tags: spoofing

Someone sent me a txt that was old, from a number that I recognize.  It originally was from that person months ago, but they erased it. It was resent to me and I was supposed  to have sent messages to a phone...I didnt.
How could  this happen.

Comment: could you please provide more information. Do you mean a textfile or an textmessage?

Comment: Are the texts from around valentine's day? It's probably related to [a glitch in a major mobile carrier](https://www.reddit.com/r/RBI/comments/dszzuo/mysteriously_early_this_morning_scores_of_people/)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a server issue at Syniverse which is being reported today by the media.  See https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/11/why-168149-valentines-day-text-messages-arrived-in-november/.